# Android Json result display in webview

Tags: android, listview, webview, alphabetical-sort

In my JsonParsing  and i got the result from the json. I need to display that result in webview after clicking on button.
How should i do that?

**Code**  is here:

```
     TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle  = getIntent().getExtras();

           String id = bundle .getString("id");
           String firstName = bundle.getString("firstName");
           String lastName = bundle.getString("lastName");
           String headline = bundle.getString("headline");
           String pictureUrl = bundle.getString("pictureUrl");
           String url = bundle.getString("url");


          Log.v("LV","id :"+id+"\n"+"firstname :"+firstName+"\n"+"lastname :"+lastName+"\n"+"headline :"+headline+"\n"+"pictureUrl :"+pictureUrl+"\n"+"siteStandardProfileRequest"+url);
          tv.setText("id :"+id+"\n"+"firstname :"+firstName+"\n"+"lastname :"+lastName+"\n"+"headline :"+headline+"\n"+"pictureUrl :"+pictureUrl+"\n"+"Profile URL :"+url);
```

Comment: Is it essential that your button will be inside the webView? Is it ok for your application to put the button outside the webView (as a normal button)?

Comment: please see my edit...  user2695685

Comment: There is no button inside webview. If i click a button then it will display the result in webview.,,, @Zbun

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.webview;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
private TextView tv;
private final static String content = "<html><body><button    onclick=\"window.jsToJava.nativJava()\">Show Json</button></body></html>";
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        showJson();
    };
};

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "jsToJava");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, consoleMessage.message(), 1)
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");

}

@JavascriptInterface
public void nativJava() {
    Log.i("AABB", "HEREaaaa");
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
}

public void showJson() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id = bundle.getString("id");
    String firstName = bundle.getString("firstName");
    String lastName = bundle.getString("lastName");
    String headline = bundle.getString("headline");
    String pictureUrl = bundle.getString("pictureUrl");
    String url = bundle.getString("url");

    Log.v("LV", "id :" + id + "\n" + "firstname :" + firstName + "\n"
            + "lastname :" + lastName + "\n" + "headline :" + headline
            + "\n" + "pictureUrl :" + pictureUrl + "\n"
            + "siteStandardProfileRequest" + url);
    tv.setText("id :" + id + "\n" + "firstname :" + firstName + "\n"
            + "lastname :" + lastName + "\n" + "headline :" + headline
            + "\n" + "pictureUrl :" + pictureUrl + "\n" + "Profile URL :"
            + url);
}

}

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```